# Error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" when set a margin to table

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, exception

I try set **Margin** for **Table** in code behind but can't, just have exception: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." My code:

```
Table table = new Table();
Image picture = GetPicture(pictureName);
double leftMargin = (MAX_PICTURE_WIDTH - picture.Width) <= 0 ? 0 : (MAX_PICTURE_WIDTH - picture.Width);
table.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin, 0, 0, 0);
```

In last row when set a margin I have exception.
So why? How solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        Table table = new Table();
        table.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin, 0, 0, 0);
    });
```

or

```
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() 
     { 
           Table table = new Table();
           table.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin, 0, 0, 0); 
     });
```

Maybe try creating the table on the UI thread.

Comment: No, can't use lambda, can use just delegate. Have next:

Comment: App.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate{table.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin, 0, 0, 0);});

Comment: First, why can't you use a lambda? Second, what do you mean by "But problem the same"? The proposed answer should solve the problem you describe (although the fundamental problem is that you're trying to modify the UI from the wrong thread, and you might do better to fix that).

Comment: Error 8 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @Leo And you say `But problem the same` ....

Comment: Well, I found resolve: in method "One(){...}" I start Thread operation, and in this thread I create Table. It invoked error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.". So resolve is next: I took out creating of a Table beyond of One() method (beyond of main Thread). But it's incomprehensible why creating of table throws this error. But it works.

Comment: It's not incomprehensible at all.  Keep UI stuff on the UI thread.